# Is there a performance hit using COUNT(*) over COUNT(attributeName) in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

Is there a performance hit using COUNT(*) over COUNT(attributeName) in T-SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `attributeName` is nullable, these are different constructs which yield different results, since `COUNT()` does not count `NULL` values.

The `attributeName` should be fetched and evaluated in the latter case.

If it's not (and defined as `NOT NULL`), then there is no performance difference and they are optimized to use the same plan.

Answer (score 0):

They are different queries so performance shouldn't matter...

But COUNT only looks at [NULL vs NON-NULL expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1/1221649#1221649)